# Debugging Django project in Aptana

Tags: django, debugging, aptana

I'm developing some Django project in Aptana Studio. Today, I was really confused about some debugging problems that occured while I rearranged my project a little.
At first, I was using basic project structure, that is `projectFolder/appFolder` and here I had basic files as well, that is `models.py, urls.py` and `views.py`. I was able to set breakpoints and what's more important they were hitten (yeah, not always it's trivial).
Then I decided to rearrange my project a little bit. I extracted some code from `views.py` and put it into `authorization.py`. I also created a new folder `views` and inserted `authorization.py` in that folder. All files (including `views.py`) stayed where they had been before. What really made me tearing my hair out is the fact that now breakpoints in `authorization.py` were not hitten, while all views from that file were returning correct templates! Breakpoints in `views.py` worked perfectly fine.
Can anyone explain why this little refactoring caused so much trouble for debugging, and in the same time did not change anything in behaviour of website?